# Ubuntu 20.04 - Display glitches after wake up

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend

Since installing Ubuntu 20.04 last June, I was getting some glitches after monitor's wake up and those were going away after just passing the mice cursor in it. Note that those graphic glitches are very specific because I'm getting them only on my 2nd monitor which has Google Chrome open.

Since about a week now I'm noticing that those glitches are still on the 2nd monitor and my Chrome's tabs but now I can't just pass my cursor on it to make them going away. Those are way more pronounced than before and the only solution is to close my Google Chrome and open it again.

This is not a huge deal but I was wondering if anyone is experiencing the same thing ?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Graphic: Nvidia Geforce 970 GTX , Nvidia 440 driver (Same driver since I initially installed Ubuntu)

Edit: I also notice the glitches seem to be there when the computer was actually in deep sleep.

Cheers!
Xzi.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Nvidia and don't know why. I have to restart Chrome.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on Debian Sid with a Quadro T2000 using driver 450.66

Comment: What's the chrome version?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspend-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to disable hardware acceleration in the settings.

Comment: I think disabling hardware acceleration would slow down chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I just started facing this issue too with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS ( which I've been using since 2 years). I think it's linked to the new Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). I reinstalled NVIDIA drivers (a couple of them 390, 415, 430, 450) that didn't solve the problem.

Anyway by disabling hardware acceleration in CHROME settings, I don't have this issue anymore.
I'll update this post once I have more details.

### Edit 1

Upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 resolved the issue for me. I'm using NVIDIA-driver-450 property tested.

### Edit 2

Once again  I update chrome and I'm starting to have the issue in chrome Version 86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (64-bit). I'm using NVIDIA-driver-450 property tested.

Comment: Same here. It didn't always do this, I think a recent update broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Same here with driver version 440 on a Dell Latitude 5590 with Nvidia GeForce MX130. It's Maxwell-based like your GTX970. I wonder if there is anyone having the same issue with a newer card (Pascal, Turing).

I tried the alternative driver, 440-server, without success. So I went back to the 435, which works fine without glitching – at least I did not observe any problems in the last days. Seems like we have to wait for the next update from Nvidia.
Meanwhile [change the graphics driver in "Software & Updates > Additional Drivers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNx0h.png) to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I chose the nvidia-driver-435 package, and it is listed as being used in the Additional driver tab, but nvidia-settings shows 440.82! Chrome waking-from--suspend-black-UI bug is still there.