# 20.04 - Google Chrome Display Glitches after wake up

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, google-chrome, display-resolution

If I had chrome opened, and I put my laptop to sleep. When I log back in, google chrome's display gets distorted and becomes black (seen in screenshot below).

All tabs becomes black and when I move the mouse over the black spaces, the black squares move.

This problem started happening when I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm using NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] and Nvidia 440 driver.

[image]

Comment: i can confirm this behavior with latest Chrome and Nvidia on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS.

Comment: Have you submitted a bug? I confirm exactly the same bug on Thinkpad P14s (NVIDIA Corporation GP108GLM [Quadro P520] (rev a1))

Comment: Same bug happens but it affects everything, if I tried to use an application with a list and tries to scroll, graphics become glitchy in this area. I get this bug on bıth elementaryos and popos with mx150 and 440 drivers.

Comment: I haven't submitted a bug yet, II wasn't sure if it was only happening to me.

Comment: Can confirm the same issue on Ubuntu 20 and Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 on a system with GeForce MX150 and running NVIDIA driver 440.100

I had previously faced this issue on Ubuntu 16, some months ago, and it was resolved by using a older version  of the NVIDIA driver. This did not work for me this time around, though.

Comment: According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1272298/669558) using the older 435 driver solved the issue. I tried changing it again myself and the issue has not replicated yet. Maybe you can try it as well?

Comment: Same issue on ubuntu 20.04 with chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit) and GeForce GTX 970 with Nvidia Driver Version 440.100.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, nvidia-384, GTX 1070, same thing.

Comment: Go to `chrome://flags` and enable  `ignore-gpu-blacklist` and `enable-vulkan`. Works like a charm!

Comment: [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271103/ubuntu-20-04-display-glitches-after-wake-up) suggests disabling hardware integration in Chrome's settings. Worked for me with Ubuntu 20.04 and GeForce GTX650 Ti.

Comment: @alexeydemin You should post that as the answer below! This problem has been driving me crazy for weeks, and that finally fixed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with Chrome browser after suspending the computer on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspending-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the `enable-vulkan` option which worked but I ended up having a lot of lag. I found another option that is to add `--use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop` when launching.

I.e. I copied the `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` and edited the `Exec` line to add those options.

Comment: Other's previous solutions didn't work for me. I'd like to try yours. Can you copy/paste your exact exec= line?

Comment: `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop %U`

There's 3 Exec lines you'll need to modify to get "New Window" and "New Incognito Window"

Answer (score 0):

I copied `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`, by running:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then I gave myself the property of `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, by running:

```
sudo chown $USER: ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

And replaced each occurence (there must probably be 3) of `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` by `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop`
(keeping whatever comes before or after exactly like it is already), by running:

```
sed -i -e 's/\/usr\/bin\/google-chrome-stable/\/usr\/bin\/google-chrome-stable --use-cmd-decoder=validating --use-gl=desktop/g ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

And now it works without having to disable hardware acceleration!